# Can you change the location/endpoint of a dynamic web reference at run-time in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, web-services, jira

In a fairly standard fashion, I created a Web Reference to a SOAP service in Jira for an extension that I'm building (Jira is an issue tracker for those unfamiliar with it). Visual Studio auto-generates a `.Settings` file and an `app.config` that contains the web service URL.

Since I'm developing an extension/plugin to an ALM product we're building, the *consumer* of the extension will be the one who ultimately decides where this web service points to, because it will be integrated with the consumer's instance of Jira. Assume that the web service URL would be stored and pulled from a database.

How can I get the auto-generated service to use a URL from a database instead of from the generated `app.config`?

*Note: we are using v2.0 of the framework, so WCF is not an option.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even in the 2.0 web service you should be able to change the "Url" property of your web service proxy to the value you desire.

Comment: Where is this "Url" Property located?

Comment: .Net 3.5 appears to handle this completely differently. I use to use this method in my old, .Net 2.0 project.  Anyone know how to do this with C# 3.5?  I assume I could get it to work by changing the Endpoint.Address setting, however, this doesn't work one address uses SSL and the other doesn't.  How can I reset the Endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor of the client that admits the uri.

Comment: It didn't seem to be in the constructor, I had to use the Url property as suggested by Otávio

Comment: You have it in the constructor, but it is easier doing it with the url property as Otavio suggested:
HelloWorld.HelloWorldClient hello =
new
HelloWorld.HelloWorldClient("BasicHttpBinding_IHel loWorld",
new
EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8888/BasicHost/HelloWorld"));